# Few issues after installing MVC 4 on visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have installed MVC 4 on visual Studio 2010.
Previously MVC 2 and 3 have been installed as well

Everything works fine but when trying to add a controller, I get the following error:

[image: Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute']

The way I add it :

```
right click on Model folder > add > controller
```

When I clean the project and retry it works.
But each time I build it then I get the error again untill I clean again.

I can live with that but I realized I cannot add a view(model class) either, the wizard would just close as soon as I check `Create a strongly-typed`

How can I fix these issue? I know it is related to the Entity framework, but I don't know what to do at this point.

I tried uninstalling then reinstalling using the the console and also NuGet, problem still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on vs 2010 with mvc 4,   I use mvc 4 with vs 2012,  while you may not have that luxury, you are certainly running into legitimate conflicts with projectguids or assembly references etc...

A few things I suggested in the past may NOT be what you are looking for , I will look further for a solution to your problem, in the interim, see these stackoverflow links

[Build Errors - 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelClientValidationRule' Conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512021/build-errors-system-web-mvc-modelclientvalidationrule-conflicts/9551791#9551791)

[ModelClientValidationRule conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510484/modelclientvalidationrule-conflict/9551774#9551774)

Comment: yes there's a conflict because it is still pointing to the old EF (4.3.1.0)

Comment: manually delete it out of your package.config file  e.g.  delete this line  <package id="EntityFramework" version="4.3.1.0" />

Comment: I rolled back to 4.3.1.0 it works now but I cannot use using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; so I had to comment it out. How could this affect my project

Comment: not being able to use it?  Be sure to right click on references in the project and add it first that way.  You will be missing the ability to decorate with attributes -- this might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981617/system-componentmodel-dataannotations-schema-not-found