# How do you remove old version of entity framework in GAC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Yesterday I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906303/few-issues-after-installing-mvc-4-on-visual-studio-2010) about a issue related to entity framework version after installing MVC 4 on visual studio.

Somehow visual studio is still pointing to the old version of the dll (4.3.1.0) eventhough I manualy set it in my reference to the new one

I tried solution suggested by danielovich `gacutil /u "EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`

But it did not find it

`No Assemblies Found Matching EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

If I look in my project file I can see:
`<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

Which is the new version I am trying to use. I wonder if the DLL is being referenced from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
gacutil /u <fully qualified assembly name>
```

Try this:

```
gacutil /u "EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

EF 4.+ is not designed to be GAC'ed, it's designed to be bin deployed.

Comment: Hi I just tried it : `No Assemblies Found Matching EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`
I updated my question