# Error on upgrading to Entity Framework 6.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've upgraded my solution (WebApi) from EF 6.1.3 to 6.2 using Nuget.

My models and context are in a separate assembly than the main WebApi project. There is no `entityframework` section in the WebApi project `web.config`. However, there is one in the other assemblies' `app.config` referencing EF

Everything was working fine before the upgrade. Now, after upgrading, I'm getting:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I've tried various answers from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641435/error-no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invarian), but it still doesn't work (I get other exceptions when trying to use other suggested answers).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks for putting this question here. I was about to upgrade EF in my webapi projects. You saved my day(s).

Comment: Try to also install EF to all of your projects, which have reference to assembly with your context and ensure, that corresponding EF section exists at their web.config.